# Backbone destroy model, get method or request payload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

When I destroy a model (DELETE) does the id goes directly in the query string (/rest/id)  or in the request payload (json in http body) ??

Comment: Why not look at your network inspector in the console and find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does.

```
create → POST   /collection
read → GET   /collection[/id]
update → PUT   /collection/id
delete → DELETE   /collection/id
```